# Laravel and jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables

I am using datatable and laravel datatables from yajra.

I have the following for my view:

```
employeeTable = $('#employeeTable').DataTable({
  deferLoading: 0,
  serverSide: true,
  processing: true,
  ajax: {
    url: "{!! route('ajaxlistemployee') !!}",
    type: "POST",
    data: ajaxData,
    dataType: "JSON",
    dataSrc: function ( json ) {
        console.log(json);
        return json.data;
    }
  },
  columns: [
    { data: 'id', name: 'id'},
    { data: 'name', name: 'name'},
    { data: 'manager_id', name: 'manager_id'},
    { data: 'manager_name', name: 'manager_name'},
    { data: 'is_manager', name: 'is_manager'},
    { data: 'region', name: 'region'},
    { data: 'country', name: 'country'},
    { data: 'domain', name: 'domain'},
    { data: 'subdomain', name: 'subdomain'},
    { data: 'management_code', name: 'management_code'},
    { data: 'job_role', name: 'job_role'},
    { data: 'employee_type', name: 'employee_type'},
  ],
  columnDefs: [
    {
        "targets": [0, 2], "visible": false, "searchable": false
    }
  ]
});
```

I also have my repository:

```
public function getEmployeeList($where = null){
  $employee = \DB::table('employee AS E')
    ->select(
      'E.id',
      'E.name',
      'E.manager_id',
      'M.name AS manager_name',
      'E.is_manager',
      'E.region',
      'E.country',
      'E.domain',
      'E.subdomain',
      'E.management_code',
      'E.job_role',
      'E.employee_type'
    )->join('employee AS M', 'E.manager_id', '=', 'M.id');

  if (!empty($where['manager']))
  {
    $employee->where(function ($query) use ($where) {
      foreach ($where['manager'] as $w)
      {
        $query->orWhere('E.manager_id',$w);
      }
    });
  }

  return $employee;
}
```

And I have my Ajaxcontroller:

```
public function getAjaxListEmployee(Request $request){
  $input = $request->all();
  $return = $this->employeeRepository->getEmployeeList($input);
  $data = Datatables::of($return)->make(true);
  return $data;
}
```

It is pretty simple and everything is working except that the search and sort are not working.

I don't understand why and I tried a lot of different configurations.
But none are working to get me what I need.

Comment: Open developer tools in the browser and see what errors you are getting.

Comment: @Richard check for errors in console and post it here

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after a lot of trials and errors, I think I understand why this was not working.

It seems for the datatables function in Laravel to work correctly, you cannot use as with the definition of the table.

In the code :

```
public function getEmployeeList($where = null){
  $employee = \DB::table('employee AS E')
    ->select(
      'E.id',
      'E.name',
      'E.manager_id',
      'M.name AS manager_name',
      'E.is_manager',
      'E.region',
      'E.country',
      'E.domain',
      'E.subdomain',
      'E.management_code',
      'E.job_role',
      'E.employee_type'
    )->join('employee AS M', 'E.manager_id', '=', 'M.id');
```

By just changin it to:

```
public function getEmployeeList($where = null){
  $employee = \DB::table('employee')
    ->select(
      'employee.id',
      'employee.name',
      'employee.manager_id',
      'M.name AS manager_name',
      'employee.is_manager',
      'employee.region',
      'employee.country',
      'employee.domain',
      'employee.subdomain',
      'employee.management_code',
      'employee.job_role',
      'employee.employee_type'
    )->join('employee AS M', 'employee.manager_id', '=', 'M.id');
```

It worked fine after that.

I hope this will help others as it was very difficult to find...